# Twitter Bootstrap button toggle - How to make on/off state color contrast more obvious

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap, colors, toggle

I am using the button toggle feature of Twitter Bootstrap.  Everything works perfectly.  The problem is the color difference between the toggle's on/off state is too similar.  It is hard to see the difference between on and off states.

Ideally I'd like to make the color contrast more pronounced between on/off states, or change the color entirely between states (e.g. blue = off, red = on).

```
<button type='button' class='btn' data-toggle='button' value='ABC'><i class='icon-star-empty'></i></button>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Recently also met this problem.
found a quick solution

bootstrap-3.1.1

in line 209 from `bootstrap.js`

Change

```
if (changed) this.$element.toggleClass('active')
```

to

```
if (changed) this.$element.toggleClass('btn-success')
```

Comment: Great workaround buddy, but it is a good practice not to change the native source code of bootstrap. Anyways, if it's a bearable problem it's a great solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I realized I could change the class using JQuery.  Now off-state is white, on-state is green.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('.keyContactToggle').click(function (e) {

   var UserID = $(this).attr('value');

 if ( ($(this).is('.btn')) && ($(this).is('.keyContactToggle')) && !($(this).is('.btn-success')) ) {

   $(this).addClass('btn-success');


 } else {

   $(this).removeClass('btn-success');

 }

});

});
```